# The larger an encoding dimension in NLP the better?

Tags: nlp, encoding

Is the longer encoding array (word2vec or any other kind) always more precise than the shorter (not regarding the computational cost, only the performance)?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What do you mean by "the sorter"?  Please edit the question to provide additional context, clarify what you are asking, show us what research you've done and what you've found, and share with us your reasoning or your thoughts based on the research you've done.

Comment: Do you mean shorter?

Comment: Yes, I definitely meant sHorter, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't that way. From my personal experience, I have built custom word2vec's to some datasets and observed that at times, shorter vectors did better than longer ones. I think you can try shorters length vectors for smaller datasets. I cannot tell any metric in specific for comparison of dataset size and word2vec length though.

Comment: OK, thank you. But what is "shorter" and "longer"? 50-long is short?

Comment: 50 according to me is short. 300 is the maximum I have used, it is the same as pre-trained google w2v. The range 50-300 seems optimal for me.

Answer (score 0):

50-300 is the range of dimensions I would use. If you go through the word representation papers, most uses 200 or 300 dimensions.

Skip thought uses 500 I think but it is a representation for sentences.

Oh and to answer your question, not always. It obviously depends on the size of your training data but also your task at hand.